# Keeping the namespaces in c# soapservice

Tags: c#, soap, reference, namespaces, soap-client

I guess it is a stupid question but I'm havin a hard time finding something like it, so maybe someone here can push me in the right direction.

Problem:
I have a c# SoapService with lots of request/response classes, so let us say:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://fuu.bar.gov/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class Main : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [SoapHeader("authentication")]
    [WebMethod(Description = "Get Foo")]
    public FooResponse GetFoo(FooRequest request)
    {
         return new FooResponse ();
    }

    [SoapHeader("authentication")]
    [WebMethod(Description = "Get Bar")]
    public BarResponse GetBar(BarRequest request)
    {
         return new FooResponse ();
    }
}

public class FooResponse{};
public class FooRequest{};
public class BarResponse{};
public class BarRequest{};
```

So when I create a WebReference named "foobarWebservice" in my client code I'll get:

```
foobarWebservice.FooResponse
foobarWebservice.FooRequest
foobarWebservice.BarResponse
foobarWebservice.BarRequest
```

class definitions.

What I'd like to is change the above into this:

```
public class Main : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [SoapHeader("authentication")]
    [WebMethod(Description = "Get Foo")]
    public Foo.Response GetFoo(Foo.Request request)
    {
         return new FooResponse ();
    }

    [SoapHeader("authentication")]
    [WebMethod(Description = "Get Bar")]
    public Bar.Response GetBar(Bar.Request request)
    {
         return new FooResponse ();
    }
}
```

which is easy:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Response{}
    public class Request{}
}
namespace Bar
{
    public class Response{};
    public class Request{};
}
```

But also the client Reference.cs should give me this:

```
foobarWebservice.Foo.Response
foobarWebservice.Foo.Request
foobarWebservice.Bar.Response
foobarWebservice.Bar.Request
```

So I'd be able to do that:

```
foobarWebservice.Main webservice = new foobarWebservice.Main();
foobarWebservice.Foo.Request newRequest = new foobarWebservice.Foo.Request();
foobarWebservice.Foo.Response response = webservice.GetFoo(newRequest);
```

Simply spoken: I want to keep my namespaces intact in the generated Reference.cs file on the client application.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new assembly with the namespaces and use it in both client and server projects. In client project when adding the WCF reference check the 'use existing assemblies' option and check the added reference project/assembly.

Project A: Common classes

Project B: WCF service

Project C: WCF client. Make sure to check the reuse assemblies option.